# Can't override AppBar background color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

could someone please help me with this issue.
this is the code:

```
import { AppBar } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
})

const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return <>
        <AppBar className={classes.root}>
            test
        </AppBar>
        <h1 className={classes.root}>test</h1>
    </>
}

export default App;
```

The question is:
why the background-color of the AppBar component is not changing;
No problem with the h1 tag thought;
The other problem I've found is, sometimes it changes, but when I refresh the page, it becomes blue -> color by default;
So, thanks a lot for the answer if there is any :);

Comment: This works fine. What's wrong on your side?

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't work with me. May be I miss something, a library or I something else. It should work, I'm sure, but it doesn't. This is what I'm trying to find out. If you have any suggestions, please. Thank you.

Comment: You don't get any errors? Have you installed `@mui/styles` dependency?

Comment: Unfortunately, got no messages. Here is the list with all dependencies:

"@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
 "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
 "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
 "@mui/material": "^5.2.3","@mui/styles": "^5.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"

Comment: Where's your ThemeProvider and customer theme?

Comment: You should able to inspect the browser and how the style was applied.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where styles applied to the AppBar component did not override some of the default styles. The fix was to wrap my component tree with `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>`. The solution looks something like this in the end:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function GlobalCssPriority() {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      {/* Your component tree. Now you can override MUI's styles. */}
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

[Link to source](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order)